# Powershell script Where-Object in foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach

Having trouble with my loop:

```
   $array =@();
    foreach($list in $Lists | Where-Object{"History", "Historic" -notmatch $list.Title}) 
    {
        $result = new-object psobject
        $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $list.Title
        $array += $result
        Write-Host $list.Title
    }
```

I want to save only the results which don't contain "History" or "Historic" in their title.

For example "Workflow blablabla - Historic" wouldn't be saved.

Can't find the right syntax of my condition: returns all results or nothing at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $lists | ? {$_.Title -notmatch 'Histor(y|ic)'} | Select Title
```

Your where clause is a regex with a regex on the right-hand side of the `-notmatch`.

This would also work:

```
$result = $lists | ? {$_.Title -notmatch 'History' -or $_.Title -notmatch 'Historic'} | Select Title
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !
Sorry of being so noob at PS... But where should I add it exactly ?

Comment: No need to add it, it is it, my code is doing what I think yours intended to do. The only difference is that I left out the `Write-Host` line.

Comment: Thanks Dave !
I finally understood how it worked !

That's work great ! Thanks for your help.